# Power BI Button Disappears when my mouse moves away

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a button in Power BI.
Using the selection pane, I have this button set to be visible, however, once my mouse isn't touching it, it is no longer visible.

Any suggestions on why and how to fix it?

**Edit #1:**

Seems to be something with the box that I have the buttons are sitting on. One button, that is not filled, stays where it's supposed to be, but the other one that is filled, is what disappears.

When I remove the red box everything is sitting on, everything is fine. Perhaps there is some transparency option I need for the box.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the object that is disappearing.
2. Select "Format" on the ribbon at the top.
3. Select "Bring Forward" or "Bring to the top".
4. How you order things in the Selection Pane is VERY important.

This fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your power bi desktop top layer tabs go **view -> selection.**

[image: img 01]

and from here you can select which visualization, images, buttons needs to come to forward.

[image]